# Counting down in increments of 5

Tags: c

I am having difficulties using a while loop to count down from the starting number 100. I need to count down in increments of 5, and display each result until i reach 20.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down( void ) {

    // Declare an integer variable that you will use to count. Initially 
    //     the counter should equal the start value, 100.
    int counter = 100;
    printf(counter);
    // Begin a WHILE statement that will execute its loop body if the counter 
    // is greater than the end value, 20.

    while (counter < 20) {
        // Print the value of the counter on a line by itself.
        printf(counter);
        // Subtract 5 from the counter.
        int new_number = counter - 5;
        printf(new_number);
    }
}


int main( void ) {
    count_down();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Your printf probably causes crash. Turn on compiler warnings and fix them! Use *-Wall -Wextra* for gcc and clang, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Fix the while condition: you are only interested in numbers above 20
2. You need to decrement the counter variable.

See the changes below:

```
while (counter > 20) {
    // Subtract 5 from the counter.
    counter -= 5;
    // Print the value of the counter on a line by itself.
    printf("%d\n", counter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your function is you're setting `count` to 100, then attempting to enter a `while` loop which will never activate (100 is never less than 20). If you were to enter this loop, no instructions inside the loop actually change the loop condition variable, so it'd run infinitely.

Beyond that, I recommend adding parameters to your function to make it reusable for any countdown and for any step:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down(int start, int end, int step) {
    while (start >= end) {
        printf("%d\n", start);
        start -= step;
    }
}

int main() {
    count_down(100, 20, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
100
95
90
85
80
75
70
65
60
55
50
45
40
35
30
25
20
```

Answer (score 1):

While other answers have commented on how to fix your approach, it should be noted that instead of a `while` loop, a `for` loop may be a better fit as it is designed for this purpose.

```
for(int counter = 100; counter >= 20; counter -= 5) {
    printf("%d\n", counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems, You never change the value of counter and your condition inside the while seems wrong.
try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down( void ) {

    // Declare an integer variable that you will use to count. Initially 
    //     the counter should equal the start value, 100.
    int counter = 100;
    printf(counter);
    // (c) Begin a WHILE statement that will execute its loop body if the 
    //     counter is greater than the end value, 20.
    while (counter > 20) {
        // Print the value of the counter on a line by itself.
        printf(counter);
        // Subtract 5 from the counter.
        counter = counter - 5;
        printf(counter);
    }
}


int main( void ) {
    count_down();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `printf` doesn't work

Comment: Check that printf...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count_down(int counter) {

 // Declare an integer variable that you will use to count. Initially 
 //     the counter should equal the start value, 100.
printf("%d\n", counter);
// Begin a WHILE statement that will execute its loop body if the counter 
// is greater than the end value, 20.

while (counter > 20) {
    // Print the value of the counter on a line by itself.

    // Subtract 5 from the counter.
    counter = counter - 5;
   printf("%d\n", counter);
}
}


int main( void ) {
count_down(100);
return 0;
}
```